# como optimizar una consulta linq c# Objeto Complejo?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

estoy haciendo un metodo que me devuelva los datos del visitador, realize este query con linq c#, que es el siguiente,

```
public async Task<Models.Visitor> GetVisitorByEmail(string email)
{
    return (from v in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Visitor>().GetList()
            where v.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()
            select new Models.Visitor
            {
                VisitorId = v.VisitorId,
                FirstName = v.FirstName,
                SecondName = v.SecondName,
                FirstLastName = v.FirstLastName,
                SecondLastName = v.SecondLastName,
                Gender = (from g in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Gender>().GetList()
                          where g.GenderId == v.GenderId
                          select new Models.Gender
                          {
                              GenderId = g.GenderId,
                              GenderName = g.GenderName,
                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                Email = v.Email,
                Telephone = v.Telephone,
                Family = (from vf in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<VisitorFamily>().GetList()
                          join f in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Family>().GetList()
                          on vf.FamilyId equals f.FamilyId
                          where vf.VisitorId == v.VisitorId
                          select new Models.Family
                          {
                              FamilyId = f.FamilyId,
                              FamilyName = f.FamilyName,
                              PhotoPath = f.PhotoPath
                          }).ToList(),
                Territory = (from vt in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<VisitorTerritory>().GetList()
                             join t in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Territory>().GetList()
                             on vt.TerritoryId equals t.TerritoryId
                             where vt.VisitorId == v.VisitorId
                             select new Models.Territory
                             {
                                 TerritoryId = t.TerritoryId,
                                 TerritoryName = t.TerritoryName,
                                 Axis = (from a in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Axis>().GetList()
                                         where a.AxisId == t.AxisId
                                         select new Models.Axis
                                         {
                                             AxisId = a.AxisId,
                                             AxisName = a.AxisName,
                                         }).FirstOrDefault(),
                             }).ToList(),
                IsActive = v.IsActive,
                PhotoPath = v.PhotoPath,
                UserTypeId = v.UserTypeId,
                UserId = v.UserId,
                CreateBy = v.CreateBy,
                CreationDate = v.CreationDate,
                ModifiedBy = v.ModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate = v.ModifiedDate,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Quisiera saber si tengo 20 visitadores por ejemplo, si el api que estoy desarrollando me dara buenos tiempos de respuesta o hay otra forma mas optima de hacerlo, ya que soy nuevo en esto de crear objetos complejos con linq c#, estoy usando ASP.NET CORE 3.1 y entityframework Core,

agradeceria la ayuda a optimizar este query que he realizado.

quedo atento a sus sugerencias

Comment: Tenes que hacer una prueba de Estres, visual studio tiene las herramientas para llevarla a cabo dicha prueba, y te dara los resultados de tiempos.